# Time-related information in directions from Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to get time-related information in directions from the Google Maps API? Not just the amount of time for the whole trip, but the amount of time each "step" of the directions takes? Or the amount of time it takes to get to a specified point on the route?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en#JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, pull out each [DirectionsStep](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsStep) object and it has a duration property.